# Фигурные, ажурные, кружевные стрелки

Tags: прилагательные

Можно ли назвать на этих часах минутную и часовую стрелки фигурными? По той причине, что имеют замысловатую форму и что части их смыкаются в фигурах. Или к ним скорее подойдут такие описательные характеристики, как ажурные и кружевные? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чего вы никогда не ставите лайки (серый верхний треугольник над ноликом)? Просто интересно. Чем больше ставите лайков, тем больше будут отвечать.

Comment: Хорошо. Я ставил ранее галочки. Теперь буду ставить галочку и лайк.

Comment: Вы можете ставить лайки всем ответам (любое количество), которые были полезными. Но галочка может быть только одна. Если будете просматривать старые вопросы, то можете лайкать все полезные ответы. За это дают 10 баллов. А баллы - это очень приятно, так как люди понимают, что не зря старались и что их ответ кому-то помог.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за сведения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фигурный - имеющий вид какой-нибудь геометрической фигуры, узора. Например: фигурная резьба.

Фигурный - имеющий сложное очертание, форму. Например: фигурная спинка кресла, фигурная мебель, фигурное печенье.

(все примеры из словарей)

Узор (геометрический) у этих стрелок явно имеется. Значит, можно их назвать фигурными.